# How to convert a string of MM-dd-yyyy to (full month)-yyyy

Tags: c#, date-format

I have a string variable with the value of 07/31/2016 and I need to convert this to show as July 2016. How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = "07/31/2016";
var date = DateTime.Parse(input);
var output = date.ToString("MMMM-yyyy");
```

See [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx).

See also [date and time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var input = "07/31/2016";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input,"MM/dd/yyyy",provider);
var output = date.ToString("MMMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Most accurate answer due to ParseExact, which provides exactly the same result on every environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

```
string iDate = "07/31/2016";
DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate);
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(oDate.Month) + "  " + oDate.Year);
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse to DateTime and call ToString() with the new format.

Comment: I did not downvote, but there was not enough detail for me to understand. After solving the issue I see you are correct. Thanks